# Git post-receive Not running

Tags: git, redmine

I've searched several questions here and haven't been able to get the answer, so I'll ask regarding my specific situation.

Real simple post-receive hook, it just curls to Redmine to force Redmine to update the views of the repo on commit. (For sake of debugging I'm also echo'ing "Post Receive Hook Go" to see

Setup:
Bare Repo /git/repos/test.git

```
$ cd ~/
$ git clone file:///git/repos/test.git
$ cd test/
$ vim somefile_gets_updated
$ git commit -a -m 'Tackling bug #1, include the bug number so Redmine will pick it up and associate it'
$ git push origin master
```

This commits and pushes as expected, but the post-receive hook does not fire

If I do
`$ curl http://localhost:3000/sys/fetch_changesets?key=cGdcUaRr8u4Rr4zXzXhr` and refresh my redmine issue page it works, hooray!

If after the push I do:

```
$ ./.git/hooks/post-receive
```

I get:

```
$ Post Receive Hook Go
```

It works, hooray!

So I know the curl works, even the post-receive works, Git just doesn't fire it

This is the hooks

```
 $ cd .git/hooks
 $ ls -l | grep post-receive
 $ -rwxr-xr-x  1 bobbydown  staff   109 Dec 22 03:42 post-receive
```

I just don't understand why git isn't running the hook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-receive hook fires after a repo *receives* pushed commits.

In your scenario, your hook should be in your *bare* repo, not the clone.

Comment: @John - What do you mean by bare repo?

Comment: @Darius.V Usually (like in this question) a bare repo is a server-side one, it doesn't have a working tree. Take a look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server

Comment: I figured out the problem why post-receive does not run. Its because my server was like client side, and bit bucket or some server like this is server side. Since I have no access to bitbucket linux server, I cannot run post-receive. But instead I used post-merge, which I can put on my server and once received files - they are merged and so hook runs. Post-merge belongs to client side category.